# Laravel 4: codesleeve/asset-pipeline, giving me blank output for js and css

Tags: php, laravel, asset-pipeline

So I'm building a theme based site in laravel 4. This already works. The theme is specified in a config file.

I'm trying to use [asset-pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline) by codesleeve to access asset files from within the theme folders which are under /app/themes/some-theme-name/assets/...

Obviously not under the public folder.

I've emptied the default paths specified in the pipeline config, and added this code to a listener file that I have set up.

```
Event::listen('assets.register.paths', function($paths) {
    $paths->add('app/themes/'.Config::get('custom.theme').'/assets/js' , 'javascripts');
    $paths->add('app/themes/'.Config::get('custom.theme').'/assets/css', 'stylesheets');
    $paths->add('app/themes/'.Config::get('custom.theme').'/assets/fonts', 'other');
    $paths->add('app/themes/'.Config::get('custom.theme').'/assets/images', 'other'); 
});
```

I know this works because if you try to request an image say /assets/test.jpg I get an image.

But if I try to access /assets/test.css I get blank output, even though there is css code in the file. Same thing with any .js files.

Any ideas about what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It could be several things but I'd start with what your css/javascript files look like (specifically the manifest files that you are using).

So for example, if you are doing `require_tree .` please note that this directory is relative  to the manifest file itself.